# Checking signed PDFs for "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed"

Tags: pdf, certificate, itext

I'm trying to check whether e-signed pdfs have not been altered since signing.
Currently using iText pdfreader and acroFields.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(signatureName)
to check if any changes to document since it was signed.
This seemed to work ok, but it covers more than just document alteration and I need to just be able to check if document altered.
I tried checking signature.SigningCertificate.IsValidNow, but no use.
I tried comparing pdfReader.Info["ModDate"] with signature.SignDate, but I don't think this is a reliable solution.

Question is: which part of acroFields or pdfReader object can I use to check "only" if document altered?

Thanks.

Comment: Just seen following - which might help:                                               "check if document hash differs from the document hash included in the signature. (Altering the document would result in such a difference.) "

Comment: *which part of acroFields or pdfReader object can I use to check "only" if document altered?* - iText does not (yet) offer high level methods to check whether only allowed changes have been applied to a PDF. The reason is that this is quite difficult to implement in general. Even Adobe Reader in its method for that has some checks which only work properly if the allowed change in question has been done as Adobe Reader would have done it itself, alternative variants of the same allowed change are not recognized by Adobe Reader.

Comment: Thanks for info. Currently looking at Spire.PDF method on signatures "VerifyDocModified". Not on free version though...

Comment: SteveMc, *"Currently looking at Spire.PDF method on signatures `VerifyDocModified`"* - out of interest, does that method do the checks you looked for?